# פטור/אסור of an ערוה by ייבום, why may ספק ערוה also be פטור?

Tags: yibbum-chalitza-levirate

יבמות דף צט

If two ladies fall to ייבום. One of them is either your mother, sister, or daughter. You don't know which one. The Gemara says you do חליצה to both of them because one of them may not be your mother and therefore there is a חיוב ייבום. Rashi says "אע"פ שהיא מחמש עשרה נשים הפוטרות צרותיהן".
"אילו היה מכירה לא היתה צריכה חליצה ועכשיו שמכירה שתיהן צריכות חליצה".

Why just because I don't know which one is the ערוה should both ladies not have ייבום?

Comment: Can you [edit] to elaborate a bit more what you're confused about? I'd think if she is even possibly your relative you can't do Yibbum with her.

Comment: ספק דאורייתא לחומרה?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!